# Dynamically update and check an array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-filters

So I have a callback function that returns a data object from the dom (there is a list of items and every time you select an item it returns it as an object). Here is the call back function:

```
$scope.fClick = function( data ) {                 
                    $scope.x = data;
                }
```

The object returned from fClick looks like this when you select an item from the dropdown : `{  name: "English",    ticked: true    }`

When you deselect it from the dropdown it would return something like this:

`{  name: "English",    ticked: false   }`

Now I keep an array something like $scope.output to maintain a list of the returned objects. However, what I want to do is add an object returned from scope.fClick to $scope.output only if there isn't an object in output already with the same property "name" value. So right now in my implementation both `{ name: "English",    ticked: false   }` and `{   name: "English",    ticked: true    }` get added to the array. Instead I want it to update the ticked property. So, for instance if if `$scope.output = {   name: "English",    ticked: false   }` and then scope.fClick returns {  name: "English",    ticked: true}. When I push this value to $scope.output I want it to the update the existing object's tick property so `$scope.output = {    name: "English",    ticked: false   }` becomes `$scope.output = {   name: "English",    ticked: true    }`

This is what I have tried:

```
$scope.fClick = function( data ) {                 
                    $scope.x = data;
                }
                $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $scope.y = $scope.x;
                },function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    var id = $scope.output.indexOf(newValue);
                    if(id === -1){
                        $scope.output.push(newValue);
                            }
                    else {
                        $scope.output[id].tick = newValue.tick;
                    }
                    console.log($scope.output);

            },true);
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Can you paste your HTML here?

Comment: `<div isteven-multi-select input-model="languages" output-model="output" button-label="name" item-label="name" tick-property="ticked"
    on-item-click="fClick(data)">
</div>` I am using the angular module isteven-multi-select

Comment: That's the only html that has the dropdown menu list and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

Set & Get selected values, name and text of Angularjs **isteven-multi-select**

```
<div isteven-multi-select
    input-model="marks"
    output-model="filters.marks"
    button-label="name"
    item-label="name"
    tick-property="ticked"
    selection-mode="multiple"
    helper-elements="all none filter"
    on-item-click="fClick( data )"
    default-label="Select marks"
    max-labels="1"
    max-height="250px">
</div>
```

Add items

```
$scope.marks= [
    { name: 'Mark I', value: 'Mark i', text: 'This is Mark 1', ticked: true },
    { name: 'Mark II', value: 'Mark ii', text: 'This is Mark 2' },
    { name: 'Mark III', value: 'Mark iii', text: 'This is Mark 3' }
];
```

Get selected item (on change)

```
$scope.fClick = function (data) {
    console.log(data.name);
    console.log(data.value);
    console.log(data.text);
    return;
}
```

Select item (Dynamically)

```
$scope.abc = function (data) {
    console.log(data.element1, data.element2);

    angular.forEach($scope.marks, function (item) {
        if (item.value == data.element1) {
            item.ticked = true;
        }
        else {
            item.ticked = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Deselect item

```
$scope.marks.map(function (item) {
    if (item.value == "")
        item.ticked = true;
    else
        item.ticked = false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following by "simulate" a **key/value map**.

**Controller**

```
(function(){

function Controller($scope) {

  $scope.data = [
    {name: 'English', ticked: true},
    {name: 'French', ticked: false}
  ];

  //Represent a map key - value
  $scope.output = {};


  $scope.update = function(index){
    //Change the ticked value by opposite
    $scope.data[index].ticked = !$scope.data[index].ticked;

    //Set the value to our map
    $scope.output[index] = $scope.data[index].ticked;
  }

}

angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', Controller);

})();
```

Here, when you will update `$scope.output`, if the key exist, it will erase it by the new value, instead of it will create a new key/value pair.

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}} {{item.ticked}} <button type="button" ng-click="update($index)">update</button></li>
    </ul>


  </body>
```

Comment: how does it get the index? so you have `$scope.data = [
    {name: 'English', ticked: true},
    {name: 'French', ticked: false}
  ];` but the next data object it gets is  {name: 'English', ticked: false} so now the value in the data array gets updated. Like that

Comment: It get the index by the `$index` variable in the `ngRepeat` directive.
You can see this : 
[ngRepeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)